# Logback, set max history files per day

Tags: java, logging, logback, rollover, log-rotation

I use `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` and `SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP` triggering policy for my logback configuration. The rollover of log files is set to happen every day and it will also be triggered if log file size goes beyond a limit.

If I do setMaxHistory(10) on `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` with a daily roll over, then it will archive all log files in last 10 days. But what I want is to set maxHIstory on SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP each day.

Is this possible with logback?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ? @Prasanna

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP and MaxHistory set to 10, the logs older than 10 days will be removed (assuming daily rollover schedule). Size is not factored in the into removal logic.

Comment: Hey, I know you are the starter of lo4j/slf4j/logback projects and I guess there is no one better to answer these questions. Can I restrict number of history files created per day using TimeBasedRollingPolicy if size is not factored into removal logic?

Comment: I am using logback.xml for configuration (unline groovy that Prasanna seems to be using). I have <maxHistory> set to 2 but I have more than 2 files, older ones are not being removed. <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
 <fileNamePattern>mylog-minute%d{mm}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
 <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
 <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
  <maxFileSize>1kB</maxFileSize>
 </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>

Comment: I notice that files do get deleted but sometimes some **much older** files are not deleted - I ended up with for instance the following log files - mylog-2012Mar05-minute30.4.log.zip, mylog-2012Mar05-minute39.0.log.zip, mylog-2012Mar05-minute39.1.log.zip and mylog-2012Mar05.log. As you can see minute30 is still there though minute31, minute32 etc. were deleted.

Comment: Any plans or JIRA to add a maxIndex option to SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP?

Comment: @Ceki 
Hi,if I have this scene,in order to keep 7 days log, how do i define the `maxHistory` attribute.
`<fileNamePattern>${REQUEST_LOG_DIR}/request_archives/%d{yyyy-MM-dd,aux}/ip_${server.ip}/port_${server.port}/request_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>`
details infer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098598/maxhistory-of-multiple-d-specifiers-in-logback-timebasedrollingpolicy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098598/maxhistory-of-multiple-d-specifiers-in-logback-timebasedrollingpolicy). Thank you very much!

Comment: maxHistory tag is applicable for log4j2 in addition to slf4j ?