# How can I configure logback to rollover based on time or size, with an absolute max on total number of files?

Tags: java, logback

Apologies if this is seen as a duplicate. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934829/logback-set-max-history-files-per-day) is very similar but not the same. I'm interested in controlling the overall number of files (really I want to control the total size used for all logs).

I want the following from log back:

- For the current file, roll over every 12 hours or the file hits 100MB.
- No matter what, don't use more than 600MB of space total (I could also say this like: don't have more than 5 backup files).

The first point seems easy. I'm aware of TimeBasedRollingPolicy, and I know I can limit the per file size, but that's not enough. I need a way of limiting the *total* number of log files, not just the total number of time periods.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own class to do this which extends SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E>. I'd still like an answer whether this is possible without writing any code.

Comment: Why don't you use <maxHistory> with rolling appender?

Comment: Because that does not do what I want.

Comment: Can you pls share your SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy

Comment: @Anand: Just posted in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time and someone asked for the code so I thought I would post it as an answer. I haven't tested it but it should serve as a reasonable example.

```
/**
 * Extends SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy to trigger based on size or time in minutes
 *
 * Example:
 *   <triggeringPolicy class="com.foo.bar.TimeSizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
 *       <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
 *       <RolloverInMinutes>35</RolloverInMinutes>
 *   </triggeringPolicy>
 *
 * This would rollover every 35min or 10MB, whichever comes first. Because isTriggeringEvent()
 * is only called when a log line comes in, these limits will not be obeyed perfectly.
 */
public class TimeSizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E> extends SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E> {
     private long MILLIS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;

     private long rolloverPeriod;
     private long nextRolloverTime;

     @Override
     public void start() {
         nextRolloverTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + rolloverPeriod;
         super.start();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isTriggeringEvent(File activeFile, final E event) {
         long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         boolean isRolloverTime = super.isTriggeringEvent(activeFile, event) ||
                 currentTime >= nextRolloverTime;

         // Reset the rollover period regardless of why we're rolling over.
         if (isRolloverTime) {
             nextRolloverTime = currentTime + rolloverPeriod;
         }

         return isRolloverTime;
     }

     public long getRolloverInMinutes() {
         return rolloverPeriod / MILLIS_IN_A_MINUTE;
     }

     public void setRolloverInMinutes(long rolloverPeriodInMinutes) {
         this.rolloverPeriod = rolloverPeriodInMinutes * MILLIS_IN_A_MINUTE;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldnt the following line be && instead of ||?   boolean isRolloverTime = super.isTriggeringEvent(activeFile, event) ||
                 currentTime >= nextRolloverTime;

Comment: I don't think so. The code should roll over if there was a triggering event OR we have passed the rollover timestamp.